# Android Keystore file

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

I work in a team and will be uploading to the Android play store soon. 
Now I have pushed apps to the play store before on my own, but this is my first time doing it within a team of people. So I just have quick questions (of which I tried googling for, but I guess my googling skills failed me).

1 - I will be uploading this app. I will be creating the Keystore file on my local machine. But what if one of my team members wants to push an update? Can I just email him the file?

2 - I understand if we lose the file, we are pretty much done. But can we upload it to a private (but shared) dropbox folder or something?

3 - What if we create a new app? Can the team use the same file for all of the apps created within the team?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - I will be uploading this app. I will be creating the Keystore file
>   on my local machine. But what if one of my team members wants to push
>   an update? Can I just email him the file?

Yes, If you send them the file, they will be able to sign the app as well.

> 2 - I understand if we lose the file, we are pretty much done. But can we upload it to a >private (but shared) dropbox folder or something?

Right. Make sure you have multiple copies of the file, but also make sure that they are stored in very secure locations.

> 3 - What if we create a new app? Can the team use the same file for all of the apps created >within the team?

Yes, one keystore file can be used to sign multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes, you can send your team members the keystore file anyway you want. Better to also send them the password used to create the keystore, so it can be used.

2- Ofcourse, just keep in mind to save where it will be safe. (ie. not stolen/lost).

3- The keystore can be used in all apps without any kind of problem.